# Get tests to run from gradle commandline

Tags: java, testing, gradle

My tests are run via gradle like

```
./gradlew -Denv=remote clean test --tests '*com.examle.Test*'
```

and before tests executing I need to get argument that specified tests to run (`*com.examle.Test*`).

Is it possible to extract this argument in **build.gradle** file?

I assume something like

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    def testsToExecute = ??? //need to get "*com.examle.Test*"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you’d like to get what is set on the command line, then there doesn’t seem to be any official way of getting that information. Even if you use [internal APIs](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/989ccc9952b140ee6ab88870e8a12f1b2998369e/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/filter/DefaultTestFilter.java#L118), then the patterns are only accesible at task execution time (i.e., not yet in the [build configuration phase](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)). The following works with Gradle 7.1 at least:

```groovy
tasks.withType(Test) {
    // only at task execution time:
    doFirst {
        // "getCommandLineIncludePatterns()" is part of the internal API only
        def testsToExecute = filter.commandLineIncludePatterns
        // "filter.includePatterns" would use the public API but doesn't contain
        // the patterns from the command line, unfortunately
    }
}
```

If you’d like to hardcode the tests to run, then you’re probably looking for [the `filter` method](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#filter-org.gradle.api.Action-) of the `Test` task. Something like the following should work:

```groovy
test.filter {
    includeTestsMatching '*com.examle.Test*'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! 
Option 1 seems to be close but unfortunately it returns null. Maybe because I don't specify explicitly includeTests/includeCategories etc. and use just `--tests '*com.examle.Test*'`

Option 2 is more about managing tests to run - I know about it but don't need for know.

Comment: Argh, you’re right, sorry! I should have tested my answer first; I’ve updated it now with a tested solution. Unfortunately, there seems to be no official way of getting the patterns from the `--tests` CLI option. Maybe your use case can be solved differently, though, e.g., by using a test execution listener?

Comment: Is there a way to specify --tests  in build.gradle, instead of thru command line?

Comment: @NickWills, that’s what the last paragraph of the answer describes – [the `filter` method](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#filter-org.gradle.api.Action-) of the `Test` task is the equivalent of the `--tests` CLI option.